# MySQL Recursive UPDATE of children rows of same table

Tags: mysql, sql, dns, sql-update, recursive-query

I am storing domain names in table, table format is

```
**id**  **node_name**           **name**     **parent_id**
    1       com                    com           null
    2       example             example.com       1
    3       test             test.example.com     2
    4       dev            dev.test.eaxmple.com   3
    5       good            good.example.com      2
```

Now my question is, I want to update "example" to "something" using MySQL recursive update query. When I update "example" to "something" I want all its children to be updated to "something".

OUTPUT:

```
**id**  **node_name**           **name**     **parent_id**
    1       com                    com           null
    2       something           something.com       1
    3       test             test.something.com     2
    4       dev            dev.test.something.com   3
    5       good            good.something.com      2
```

Thanks,
Nagesh

Comment: Currently MySQL (5.6.x) doesn't implement recursive queries. To get easily a complete path you could implement i.e. [closure table}(http://karwin.blogspot.de/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html) or nested sets.

Comment: Thanks VMai for your reply. I am new to MySql, is there any other way I can address this problem in an easy way.

Comment: You would like to update all the rows that have a parent_id of 2. Do you also want to update the rows that have a parent_id of 3 or 5?

Comment: Yes Jenn, that's what I exactly want in MySQL query. Which updates recursive children which contains parent id.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with simple select and update commands. I have tested it, it is working fine. If any one of you find any thing wrong in this statement, plz feel free to comment.

```
select id into @domainId from domain where name = 'example.com';
select name into @parentName from domain where
    id = (select parent_id from domain where name = 'example.com');
set @updatedName = concat('something', '.', @parentname);
update domain set node_name = 'something', name = @updatedName where id = @domainId;

update domain set name = concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, concat('.','example.com'), 1), '.',
 @updatedName) where name like concat('%', '.', 'example.com');
```